# C# open second form from a method and when this second form is closed continue

Tags: c#, winforms, using

I would like to do something like that

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            open a new form
            when it is closed
            Continue from here
            .
            .
            .
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
frmSecond f = new frmSecond();
f.ShowDialog() // waits until second form closed
//continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a modal dialog.

In Windows Forms, you can use the `ShowDialog` method to show a form this way:

```
secondForm.ShowDialog();
```

The basic idea is that you get a whole another UI loop running in the `ShowDialog` so that you have normal interactive GUI in the modal dialog, while your original form isn't accessible (*mostly*). When the dialog is closed, the code in the caller method continues as usual.